# Copy a range of data then paste it (automatically divided) into multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

Is it possible to copy a range of data and when pasting, it will divided automatically into multiple columns (each column has the same number of rows). As shown in this figure below, I want to copy data B2:B9 and then pasting it automatically into D2:D8, E2:E8, F2:F8.
[figure of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we533.png)

I am new to vba, so far I've tried to use macro recording but cannot get it done. I am sorry for my english, please help!

```
Range("B2:B19").Select
Selection.copy

Range("D2:D8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("E2:E8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("F2:F8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the Resize and Offset functions coupled with some basic math skills.

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitCopy()

    Dim srng As Range, trng As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, xsplit As Long, xrows As Long

    xsplit = 3  'number of target columns
    xrows = 7   'number of target rows

    With Worksheets(1)

        Set srng = .Range("B2:B19")
        Set trng = .Range("D2")

        For i = 0 To xsplit - 1
            n = Application.Min(xrows, srng.Rows.Count - xrows * i)
            srng.Resize(n, 1).Offset(i * xrows, 0).Copy _
                Destination:=trng.Offset(0, i)
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. But I have a question though, how to tweek the code in order to copy only visible data. Lets say, if I hide B3, then the code will ignore it when pasting.

Comment: Well, you cannot hide B3 but you could hide column B or row 3. If one of those was the case then you would have to work with areas of a non-contiguous range and that would be another question.

Comment: I am sorry to disturb again, can we choose the column target as we want. If i want to paste the data into D2, F2, and G2 how to do it?
My attempt is changed the line "destination code" into Destination:=trng.Offset(0, 2 * i) and i get it right for F2 but not for G2.

Comment: Probably an array of targets but again, that would be a new question.

Comment: okay, thank you so much for time and effort, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

     With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .Range("B2:B8").Copy .Range("D2:D8")
        .Range("B9:B15").Copy .Range("E2:E8")
        .Range("B16:B19").Copy .Range("F2:F4")

     End With

End Sub
```

The code does not automatically divide the whole range because you dont provide any number you want your range to be divided.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Lets say I copied a range of 10 data (B2:B19), and i want to paste it and automatically divided in to n columns with same number of rows, how do I do it with your code? n is integer greater than one (n>1).